# How to deal with phase incoherence issues after manipulating a signal in the frequency domain?

Tags: phase, stft

Let's say that we want to manipulate a signal in the frequency domain using a short time Fourier transform and once we're done , we use an
inverse STFT (plus overlap and save) to convert the results back to the time domain (this is basically a simple phase vocoder implementation).

Now, the problem is that this process doesn't retain phase information , which creates phase incoherence issues (this is evident in audible digital artifacts and in some cases the manipulated/reconstructed signal is clipped and completely 
unusable).

In my case, the STFT analysis is done using overlapping frames, which were windowed (e.g Hann, Hamming etc) prior to the FFT. 
This alone (the overlapping and windowing) creates phase incoherences, and the problem is further compounded by
manipulating spectral content.

So, are there any standard ways/strategies to deal with this kind of situation?

Thank you

Comment: I know this is kind of obvious, but: the first step would be not dropping the phase info. The STFT doesn't do that  – it's somewhere in your algorithm.

Comment: @Marcus Muller, I'm not dropping the phase info. But I am manipulating spectral content, which introduces phase incoherence. This is a known problem but I can't seem to find information on how this is best dealt with. BTW, due to the overlapping and windowing, even the STFT is not free of phase incoherence problems. When I said 'doesn't retain phase information', I meant 'it doesn't retain the original phase information exactly', not that it's discarded.