# IFFT during ISTFT - and Nyquist

Tags: stft, time-domain

Using a compilable programming language (not Librosa, Matlab, etc), I am attempting to perform ISTFT on filtered (masked) source STFT matrices obtained from NMF.  During the original construction of the mixed STFT matrix, I am using a window length of 1024, and hop length of 512.  When I run FFT on each window's $x(n)$ of length 1024, I can only use the first 512 amplitude and phase values returned, due to Nyquist.

After I generate filtered STFT's from each source after NMF, how can I estimate a $y(n)$ of length 1024 fin the time domain when I only have 512 inputs to IFFT?  (The 512 inputs for each IFFT are the elements in each column of the filtered source-specific STFTs).

Should I keep the full 1024 coefficients returned from the original FFTs, and use a mixed STFT with dimensions $1024 \times \#windows$ as the basis for the entire analysis?

Last, the filtered source-specific STFT matrices will not provide real and complex values returned from an FFT, which are required for IFFT.  Thus, my logic tells me OLA is a method to side-step IFFT.

Comment: What kind of input (real or complex) do you pass to your (S)TFT procedure?

Comment: Thanks, amplitude is sent to the STFT, based on $amp_i=\sqrt{y_{i,real}^2 + y_{i,imag}^2}$

Comment: Reading a lot of papers by author groups at Telecom-ParisTech, and some of them implement $|\mathbf{X}|^{.2}$ in STFT. Is that power or amplitude squared?  I pretty much learned that power spectrum data do not work in STFT?

Comment: actually that equation is for obtaining the magnitudes, not amplitudes. The FFT algorithm always works internally with complex numbers. That said, you have two options when passing values to an FFT procedure a) creating a complex array consisting of real values (your samples) and imaginary values (all zeros) or b ) passing an array of real values, which are then interpreted/parsed by the FFT procedure as complex values (e.g even samples are interpreted as real and odd as imaginary).

Comment: Note that for real input, the FFT procedure has to be able to recreate the top N/2 spectrum (using the FFT symmetry) if you wish to use it for reconstruction purposes. Perhaps you can post your code so we can have a look.

Comment: For the FFT, I don't know the imaginaries and therefore can only send the 1024 windowed (i.e., Hann) signal data from the .wav.  The STFT receives the calculated magnitudes based on the real and imaginary values returned from the FFT.

Comment: For the ISTFT, I now run NMF on a $(1023 \times W)$ $\mathbf{V}$ matrix constructed from the first 512 rows of the STFT matrix, with rows 513 to 1023 based on STFT rows $511, 510,\ldots,1$.  So $\mathbf{V}$ is entirely based on N/2.  The source-specific $F \times W$ Weiner mask arrays from NMF are then multiplied by the original STFT values, which are then applied to the real & imag (phase) values (from FFT) and sent to the IFFT.  Before IFFT, applying $\hat{\mathbf{V}_k}$ to phase does not work as well as applying masked original STFT values to phase.

Comment: ok it seems that you're doing real FFT. Note that in the reconstruction step (IFFT) you first have to apply the IFFT on every (overlapping) STFT frame. Once you've done that, you should use OLA to reconstruct the output signal. Your output signal will advance by 512 samples (hop size) for each iteration (the number of iterations is equal to the number of overlapping frames). Still, this procedure works fine when the original magnitudes and phases are not modified. Otherwise, you will probably have to implement the Griffin Lim algorithm.

Comment: I stand corrected, NMF is run on only a $512 \times W$ $\mathbf{V}$ matrix from rows 1 to 512 of STFT. Then, $\mathbf{XmagHat}_k$ is constructed from rows $1,2,\ldots,512,511,\ldots,1$ of $\hat{\mathbf{V}_k}$, which is then applied to phase and sent to IFFT.  (See slide 103 of https://ccrma.stanford.edu/teaching/~njb/sstutorial/part2.pdf).  However, I dont use the phase modified $\hat{\mathbf{V}_k}$ for IFFT, I multiply the original STFT by the mask array $\mathbf{M}_k$, and use that for IFFT.

Comment: Sorry, I multiply the $512 \times W$ $\hat{\mathbf{M}}_k$ Weiner mask array from NMF by the first $512 \times W$ subset of the $1024 \times W$ mixed STFT to get $\hat{\mathbf{MSTFT}}_k$. Then make Xmaghat from rows $1,2,\ldots,512,511,\ldots,1$ of $\hat{\mathbf{MSTFT}}_k$, apply phase, and run IFFT on that.

Comment: that link is dead. Still, since you're modifying your `STFT', you will have to implement a variant of the Griffin Lim algorithm. I asked this question here ( https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/61149/modified-stft-resynthesis ) but got no answers. Anyway,  I did implement the algorithm but can't be sure that it's completely correct.

Comment: The link is not dead, search on "Source Separation Tutorial Mini-Series II: introduction to Non-Negative Matrix Factorization," and you'll get a pdf link. Then check your download folder, and look on page 103 of the pdf.   I saw that eq (6) in Griffin and Lam, since it implies that IFFT and ISTFT aren't needed.   "it's the same as OLA and WOLA", and actually the estimated x(n) is a result of the calculation.

Comment: I'll have a look at that pdf. in case you're interested I can post some code that reconstructs the original signal from its STFT representation (through IFFT and OLA). The code is c++ but should be important here.

Comment: It depends on how good the code works on source separation.  I'm performing source separation with NMF (vocals vs. guitar, keyboards, drums, etc.) and have observed that most of the the text-book examples (public matlab code available) are not a cure-all and don't perform very well.  The trick is sparse methods that kill unwanted sounds - there's a lot of partial leakage of voice or keyboards into the bass sounds.  I have heard good examples, but the code is not public.

Comment: The original question was not about source separation, which is still very much a research topic and yes I agree that there's no one size fits all solution to this (which doesn't mean that won't be any in the future). Anyway, good luck with that.